# Wordpress Walker_Nav_Menu select children elements in menu based on page id

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I'm having a hard time working through the [Walker_Nav_Menu docs](http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/Nav_Menus/Walker_Nav_Menu.html). I want to have a walker that about puts the children of an element with certain id but i'm not sure exactly where to start.

I did some research but couldn't find anything based off of a Page ID. Does any one have any links or references on how to get this to work?

Thanks for the info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved!**

I was looking a it all wrong, i was trying to compare post ID instead of menu ID

here's my full walker, modified version of [Stephen Harris wp.tutsplus tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/)

if you don't pass an menu item ID it resorts to the current posts tree.

```
<?php

/* Walker Class for selecting only current nav children.
 * Modified version of Stephen Harris class that adds in support for selecting based on menu_item_id
 *
 * @param int $menu_item_id ID of the menu item you want to select off of (optional)
 *
 * @author Jake Chamberlain
 * @link http://jchamb.com
 * @author Stephen Harris
 * @link http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/
 */


class Selective_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    var $menu_item;

    function __construct($menu_item_id = false) {

        $this->menu_item = $menu_item_id;
    }


    // Don't start the top level
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
        if( 0 == $depth )
            return;
        parent::start_lvl($output, $depth,$args);
    }

    // Don't end the top level
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
        if( 0 == $depth )
            return;
        parent::end_lvl($output, $depth,$args);
    }

    // Don't print top-level elements
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
        if( 0 == $depth && !$this->menu_item )
            return;
        parent::start_el($output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
       if( 0 == $depth && !$this->menu_item )
          return;
        parent::end_el($output, $item, $depth, $args);
    }

    // Only follow down one branch
    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {

         // Check if element as a 'current element' class
         $current_element_markers = array( 'current-menu-item', 'current-menu-parent', 'current-menu-ancestor' );
         $current_class = array_intersect( $current_element_markers, $element->classes );

         if( !$this->menu_item)
         {                      
            // If element has a 'current' class, it is an ancestor of the current element
            $ancestor_of_current = !empty($current_class);       

            // If this is a top-level link and not the current, or ancestor of the current menu item - stop here.
            if ( 0 == $depth && !$ancestor_of_current)
                return;

            parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
         }
         else
         {       
            if ( $this->menu_item != $element->menu_item_parent )
                return;

             parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're a ROCK STAR!! Thanks for posting your solution!

Comment: Awesome @Jake Chamberlain , exactly what I was looking for!